# Were my questions on Meta deleted?

Tags: support

I remember asking a few questions on meta.SO. I was therefore surprised to see my question count as 0. What happened to my questions?

Comment: Was this before the old meta.stackoverflow.com became the network-wide http://meta.stackexchange.com ? Check your account there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The questions were not deleted they just moved. Meta was [split earlier this year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228888/operation-split-all-the-metas-shall-commence-on-april-16-2014).  Your questions were on the "original meta" so they are now on your [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/164553/aitchnyu?tab=questions&tt=activity) profile.

This Meta is specifically for Stack Overflow, the other Meta is for all of the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Technically the questions weren't moved.  They stayed where they were, it was MSO that moved.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Yes, moved in the sense that they are no longer attached to the meta on SO.

Answer (score -1):

Old MSO is MSE now, so check [your profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/164553/aitchnyu) on MSE for your old questions. New MSO is per-site meta of SO.